# upload HttpPostedFileBase file along with some parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to consume webservice that have a method like this:

```
SubmitUser(UserReg user, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
   // webservice side processing`
}
```

UserReg is a custom class on webservice side that have several properties like username,id,latitude,longitude etc..

I have to submit my data through this method and save webservice response after execution of 
this method. All this action will perform on button click. How can I do this all.

I am using .net framework 4.5 and mvc 4

**Note**: i am only end user of webservice

**Update1**: SubmitUser is a webservice side method and my URL is

`somepage.com/api/SubmitUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an HttpClient which can send a `multipart/form-data` encoded request:

```
byte[] imageData = ...
var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageData);
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

// Add the image
requestContent.Add(imageContent, "image", "image.jpg");

// Now add some additional parameters that will be bound to the UserReg object
requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("value1")), "param1");
requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("value2")), "param2");
requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("value3")), "param2.subparam1");

var client = new HttpClient();
var res = client.PostAsync("http://your_web_service_endpoint", requestContent).Result;
```

Comment: what will be inside the `imageData` image path or `system.drawing.Image` object or byte converted image.

Comment: It must be a byte array. So if you already have a `System.Drawing.Image` you need to first convert it to a byte array.

Comment: and sorry i don't remember that webservice response will be returned  in json formate and please tell me little bit how i can get its response from json

Comment: The result you will get from the call could be used to read the response data: `string json = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. Or you could directly deserialize it back to some view model using the other methods. Look at the available methods on the response.

Comment: your answer is usefull tell me a last thing. `SubmitUser` method that is on webserivce side looking as taking two argument as i mentioned in question. tell me how it use `requestcontent` for both argument or how this method will consume `requestcontent` are you confident that your solution will full fill the requirment.

Comment: It doesn't matter that your ASP.NET MVC controller action takes 2 arguments. As long as the client sends correct request the default model binder will populate them. As you can see from my example I am sending 4 parameters to the request payload: `image`, `param1`, `param2` and `param2.subparam1`. The `image` parameter is a byte array that represents the image. It also has a filename and content type. The other 3 parameters are simple string values. You should of course adapt their names to match your model properties.

Comment: i done as you ask but my webservice response me "error msg" and "insufficient input"                                                       **Edit**: one thing more `userReg` having some different type of argument like `string name;`and `float latitude;` what should i do. You suggest me to use stringContent but where goes my float and int values.

Comment: It's important to send a parameter with the same name as your model property name. The value could be .ToString-ed. It could be float, int, ... For example: `requestContent.Add(new StringContent(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(5.45.ToString())), "param1");`

Comment: model properties are on param1 side? i think this error because am doing it opposite direction